# Lowest average to bowl a 300 game?

Tags: trivia, scoring, records, bowling

What is the lowest sanctioned average to bowl a perfect 300 game?

I'm sure someone who is not a really good bowler got lucky and threw 12 strikes in a game. I wonder how bad that bowler was. I looked around, but could not find any info. I'm guessing it's probably around 140.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the sidebar on [this article](http://www.usatoday.com/sports/bowling/2002-12-03-cover-300_x.htm) from 2002, it says:

> Lowest average with a 300 game
>
> Men: Roger Evans, Champaign, Ill. — 127 avg., 1991
>   Women: Diane Ponza, Santa Cruz, Calif. — 112 avg., 1977-78 season

I haven't been able to find anything more current.

There used to be a searchable database of every sanctioned 300 game rolled at the Bowling Museum and Hall of Fame.  But, since they've moved to Texas, I don't know if that's still available.

Answer (score 4):

Surf Bowl in Santa Cruz CA in 1978.  Diane Ponza bowled a 300 with a league average of 112.  I was the pinsetter mechanic on duty when she did it.  She used an 8lb pink house ball, rolled 10 straight and thought she was done so she put the ball back on the rack.  We had to tell her she had two more to go and she got the ball and rolled two more strikes.  I had to shut down that lane and box the pins for inspection.  The ABC came out and inspected the pins, ball, and lane conditions and sanctioned the 300 the next day.

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. While this record was mentioned in the existing answer, the additional details are very interesting and make the answer more than a mere factoid from a record book. We hope you can share more useful information like this.